# How to convert a .csv to .json on upload

Tags: javascript, python, type-conversion

I have a .csv file that is uploaded (when updated) on my hosting via FTP from a remote software.

This file lists some objects.

I would like that this .csv is converted into a .json every time is updated.

Is that possible? Do I need a special setting in my hosting?

Many thanks in advance for the tips

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and check out guidelines for [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If after searching this site for "convert csv to json on server" and reviewing answers, kindly update the question with server stack details and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what kind of code you're using for your file upload, which is a bit of an issue, but here are a few solutions.

For python: easiest solution (but probably not the fastest one), if you `pip install pandas` and import it, you can then run

```
f = pandas.read_csv(uploadedFilePath)
f.to_json(uploadedFilePath)
```

assuming you know where the file path is, which you should if your code uploads it.

For PHP:

```
$csv = $_POST["csv"]
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
$json = json_encode($array);

$jsonFile = fopen("{$filename}.txt", "w");
fwrite($jsonFile, $json);
fclose($jsonFile);
```

You can probably tell from the code but all this does is get the contents from the csv file (before you save the file to the server) and map it to an array, which then is just transformed into a json file and saved to the server.

For nodejs: there's a package called [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson), which, as you could probably guess, turns csv to json. All you gotta do to install it is `npm i --save csvtojson`, and then

```
const csv = require("csvtojson")
const fs = require("fs")

csv()
.fromFile(uploadedFilePath)
.then((jsonObj)=>
{
   fs.appendFile(fileName + ".json", jsonObj, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
   });

   fs.unlink(uploadedFilePath, err) => 
   {
      if (err) throw err;
   }
})
```

Which just reads the uploaded file, turns it to json, saves it into a new file, and deletes the old one. You could just skip the saving it to a new file/deleting it part and just save it to the old one, but if you do so you should probably initially save it either without an extension or with a json extension to avoid confusion.